# Making a submit button form field

Tags: django, django-forms

So there exists a snippet [here](http://djangosnippets.org/snippets/2312/):

I was going tor reuse this, but when I declare this in my forms.py, and I render the html..

```
submit_button = SubmitButtonField()
```

`value` is not supplied (it's escaped to string `None`), while `name` is default to `submit_button`, probably because of the `forms.Widget` constructor.

How can I supply the name and the value? I tried to write an init method for the widget...

```
def __init__(self, name, value, label, attrs):        
    print '%s, %s, %s, %s' %(name, value, label, attrs)
    self.name, self.value,self.label = name, value, label
    self.attrs = attrs
```

But this doesn't quite make sense if the field is always (supposedly) default to use the widget `SubmitButtonWidget`... instead I should supply these values in the field init method. But it doesn't allow me to do.

How should I rewrite this snippet so it can accept my supplied values?

Comment: How are you instantiating the form? Looks like you need to pass the value for the widget in then.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As written in the comment at the very top of the snippet, the usage is

```
submit_button = SubmitButtonField(label="", initial=u"Your submit button text")
```

Your missing value comes from the `initial` keyword argument. The name is the name of the form field.

Comment: ahh. I must be blind, too focus on the implementation. Thanks.