# How do i add <input type="button"> as a formfield in django

Tags: django, django-forms

I want to have an input field as a button in my template. Just like [this](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml5_input_type_button).I am manually rendering form fields in my template.So, how do i create a field like that in my form.

```
Formfield in forms.py

class DetailForm(forms.Form):
    owner=forms.CharField(widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'class':'form-control'}))

views.py 

def getDetail(request):
   form=DetailForm()
   return render(request,'materials/addpage.html',{'form':form})
```

and template,

```
<div class="form-group">
 {{form.owner}}
</div>
```

Comment: It will help to get a better answer if you update your question with a minimum example of a form, view and template you are using - not all the gory details, just the minimum to reproduce your problem.

Comment: @PauloScardine ,Sure, Thought no one would need the code in this case . I've added the code above.

Comment: It's not really clear what you are asking. A button is not a field, and Django won't render it whether you do `{{ form }}` or output each field separately.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Making a submit button form field](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10868873/making-a-submit-button-form-field)

Comment: Although Django lacks a native button widget there are form libraries like crispy-forms that do have button widgets.

Comment: @Selcuk Ok, hope that would do the trick. I'll try. thanks.

Comment: You can use just plain old HTML, see my answer.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

A minimal example of using buttons as input in Django looks like this:

Template:

```
<form method="POST">
 {% csrf_token %}
 <input type="submit" name="btn" value="yes">
 <input type="submit" name="btn" value="no">
</form>
{{ val }}
```

Form:

```
class Fooform(forms.Form):
    btn = forms.CharField()
```

View:

```
def test_view(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = Fooform(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            val = form.cleaned_data.get("btn")
    else:
        form = Fooform()
    return render(request, 'template.html', locals())
```

Libraries like [crispy-forms](https://django-crispy-forms.readthedocs.io/en/latest/layouts.html#bootstrap-layout-objects) have button widgets.

Comment: thanks. i'll try this one as well. Looks quite simple.

Comment: @PauloScardine  what is i want to use: `<form method="POST">
 {% csrf_token %}
 <input type="button" name="btn" value="yes">
 <input type="button" name="btn" value="no">
</form>
{{ val }}`  instead of: `<form method="POST">
 {% csrf_token %}
 <input type="submit" name="btn" value="yes">
 <input type="submit" name="btn" value="no">
</form>
{{ val }}`

Comment: @Kennerdol you can do it with a widget. Please check this link https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/ref/forms/widgets/